# How to check and skip an onClickListener?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Let's say I have a boolean **completed** that is out of the scope of the *onClickListener* that is attached to a **Button**.

What statement can I put inside this *if* block that will skip the entire code of this **Button**? (ignoring a messy solution like putting the whole code under the *else* block)

```
confirmBttn.setOnClickListener {
    if (completed) {
        *stop or skip the entire button code*
    }

    *code*
}
```

I am looking for an elegant solution to only stop that listener's block; without stopping the whole program, or using an entire if/else block. Something like a function that simply terminates the particular call for this listener function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
confirmBttn.setOnClickListener {
    if (completed) return@setOnClickListener

    *code*
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'return' keyword will stop the current scope at this point and prevents the code below to run. Other parts of your programm are not affected by this.

```
confirmBttn.setOnClickListener {
    if (completed) return

    *code*
}
```